# javascript not running when logging in with different username

Tags: javascript, jquery, asp.net-mvc, dom

so i have a website made in ASP.NET that uses JS to generate some DOM elements after getting settings from the users account.

problem is that after i sign out and log in with a different user name i get the generated elements from the previous user and i don't know why. the code that generates the elements is as follows:

```
$.ajax({
    url: '@Url.Content("~")' + 'Ticket/GetTvrtke',
    async: false,
    success: function (data) {
        document.getElementById("header_tvrtka_holder").innerHTML = data;
    }
});
```

and a little afterward its is used as such:
var tvrtke = document.getElementById("header_tvrtka_holder").innerHTML.split(", ");

```
$.each(tvrtke, function (index, value) {
    $("#KlijentMultiSelect").append("<option value=\"" + value + "\" id=\"" + index + "\" >" + value + "</option>");
});
```

now when i log off and sign in as a different user the ajax code above doesn't trigger the getTvrtke URL that gets the settings wich generate the elements and i don't know why.

Comment: Can you try setting cache to false with `$.ajaxSetup({cache: false})`? I doubt this should impact in case of different user profiles.

Comment: @ryadavilli thank you, that seemed to do the trick. post it as an answer so that  i can vote it up :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ajax by default caches the response of the calls. YOu can set it to false so that there is a fresh request every single time by using the below at the top of your application.

```
$.ajaxSetup({cache: false});
```